# Avro's GenericDatumReader writer's schema

Tags: java, avro

As stated in Avro [Getting Started](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/gettingstartedjava.html#Deserializing) about deserialization without code generation: "The data will be read using the writer's schema included in the file, and the reader's schema provided to the GenericDatumReader". Here is how GenericDatumReader is created in the example

`DatumReader<GenericRecord> datumReader = new GenericDatumReader<GenericRecord>(schema);`

But when you look at this GenericDatumReader constructor Javadoc it states "Construct where the writer's and reader's schemas are the same." (and actual code corresponds to this).

So the writer's schema isn’t taken from a serialized file but from a constructor parameter? If yes, how to read data using written schema like described on the page?

Comment: There is one constructor you can pass in both writer and reader schema:   `DatumReader<GenericRecord> reader = new GenericDatumReader<>(recordFromFile.getSchema(), readerSchema);`.   Seems to works fine if both reader and writer are in the same namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I've received an answer on Avro [mailing list](https://lists.apache.org/thread/f3nkm8xtng6zlf9fmycbw6tyswzsr5z1):

...writer schema can be adjusted after creation. This is what the DataFileReader does.

So after the DataFileReader is initialised, the underlying GenericDatumReader uses the the schema in the file as write schema (to understand the data), and the schema you provided as read schema (to give data to you via dataFileReader.next(user)).